# c++ Hidden Unique Pointer

Tags: c++11, reference, macros, unique-ptr, openfoam

I have some code which depends on some include files which are partly defined at the start of source files (which is usual) and others which are used within functions.

I typical example for that are the OpenFOAM solver sources.

Because the scheme of this code is highly procedural, but I want to put all this into a class which provides init(), run() and maybe release(), I plan to put some of the variables into the classes as private making them members.

I don't want to modify the included files because they belong to a library.

The reason for using a class is that other routines classes run together with this code.

Here is the thing. init() must prepare some variable and there situations that theses variables (being type of other clases) not explicit constructors and special arguments. It is called once. run() is called several times. The procedural code has a loop only and the contents of that loop are put into the run() method.

So the best solution was to put these variables into std::unique_ptr and init can construct whatever it needs to. Obviously with that trick the variable signature changed, so I created a second declaration of a reference like this:

```
    std::unique_ptr<volScalarField> mp_p;
    volScalarField &p = *mp_p;
```

Now this is a bit tedious so I created a macro

```
    FOAMPTR(volVectorField, p)
```

which does all the work for me:

```
    #define FOAMPTR(TYPE,NAME) std::unique_ptr<TYPE> mp_##NAME; TYPE &NAME=*mp_##NAME
```

It works pretty well, but I'm not fan of macros in general, especially if you need to debug code.

Now my question is: Is there a better way to tackle this and use something else like a template definition which might do all the magic?

**Edit:** With 'works pretty well' I mean, that the compiler can translate that. The reference though still is invalid.

**Edit:** Okay, I solved the invalid pointer problem using two Macros:

```
    #define FOAMPTR(TYPE,NAME) std::unique_ptr<TYPE> mp_##NAME
    #define FETCHFOAMREF(NAME) auto &NAME=*mp_##NAME
```

Now I put `FOAMPTR(TYPE,NAME)` to the member and I get my unique ptrs. In the `run()` method the second macro `FETCHFOAMREF(NAME)` is used. Of course init() must be sure to correctly initialize the object or else the program is going to crash.

I still leave the question open because I'm not satisfied with that solution.

Comment: You're missing one quite important thing: Creating an `std::unique_ptr` object doesn't actually allocate memory for the wrapped pointer.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I know all the pointers are set to nullptr. In the `init()` method I call `mp_##NAME.reset(new ##TYPE)`. It must be done that way, otherwise the run() method is likely to fail, not ideal...

Comment: @Gerstrong but this way your reference is invalid.

Comment: Maybe `boost::optional` or `std::experimental::optional` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @TartanLlama `optional` is close to what I am looking but I need references. Using `optional` I still have to dereference in order to get the value. I could define references at some part of the code and dereference, then let the `#include` does its stuff. But I want to avoid all that extra code.

Comment: @TartanLlama Thanks for the hint, this cannot work! The macro will always dereference the nullptr.